# Removing backslash in windows env variables in shell

Tags: shell, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have a problem with properly passing environment variable to shell script. I run pipeline on Windows machine:

```
pipeline{
  environment{
    PATH="C:/Git/bin" //point to sh.exe
  }
  stages{
    stage{
      steps{
        sh "run.py $WORKSPACE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `$WORKSPACE` has a value `C:\Jenkins\workspace\example` but when I pass its to script the backslashes are removed `C:Jenkinsworkspaceexample`. How can I overcome this problem and use Windows environment variables in shell?

Comment: Having the same issue - Windows only. Any luck?

Answer (score -1):

I have recreated the same on my Linux machine. `$WORKSPACE` is the jenkins environment variable.

Here is the working pipeline script:

```yaml
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      
      stage('Git Pull')
      {
         steps {
             echo "checkout"
         } 
      }
      stage('Run the python script') {
          steps {
              echo "$WORKSPACE"
              sh 'chmod 777 test.py' //given the executable permission to test.py script
              sh "python test.py $WORKSPACE"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works on Linux, but I have a problem with Windows